# fluentd log parsing missing new line \n for java stacktrace log

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j, kibana, fluentd

i have the below fluentd config used to parse a java stacktrace log:

```
  @id fluentd-containers.log
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/es-containers.log.pos
  tag raw.kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type multi_format
    <pattern>
      format json
      time_key time
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format multiline
      format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
      format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) \[(?<thread>.*)\] (?<level>[^\s]+)(?<message>.*)/
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z
    </pattern>
  </parse>
</source>
```

And i was expecting receive that log like shown in the syslog, something like below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at sa.com.stcs.tracking.events.ProfileType.valueOf(ProfileType.java:3)
    at sa.com.stcs.geofence.GeofenceProfileRepository.mapToGeofenceProfile(GeofenceProfileRepository.java:110)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
```

but unfortunately it comes to kibana through elasticsearch with missing new line `\n` 
see pic.[image]

**Question:** where exactly should i introduce the new line special char `\n`. ??

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `\n`. If you look at the documentation [here](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline), `format_firstline` and `format1` means fluentd will consider a new event (i.e. a new log message) when it finds something matching regex as `format_firstline` which should be date in your case. As soon as it finds the date, it parses the log message as per `format1`. It wouldn't log a new line until a line with date is encountered so you don't have to worry about it.

- The following will parse *time* (ex: `2019-11-28 22:22:14`), *thread* (ex: `pool.thread.2`), *level* (ex: `INFO`, `ERROR` etc) and *message* (ex. `java.lang....`) until it finds the next line with starting with date.

`format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) \[(?<thread>.*)\] (?<level>[^\s]+)(?<message>.*)`

- If you want to keep it simple, you can only use following which will parse log time and everything else as message:

`format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/
 format1 /^(?<logtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{1,9}) (?<log>.*)/`

Comment: The \n which I added to format1 in the question was added for testing purposes and it does not have any added value. Also, even when using your pattern, it will be similar output. As shown in kibana looks like a missing \n when printing the exception stack trace and this leads to bad log formatting. I wanna introduce it somehow in fluentd to have a log similar to what is shown in the syslog